# MySQL fails to start in EC2 after binding RDS database ip address in the EC2 configuration file. How can I connect EC2 application to RDS database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I do not want to the change the application source code where database hostname is mentioned as localhost. Now how can I make the application connect to RDS database instead of listening to localhost database?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do with "ip address binding" is not going to work.  Were you trying to bind "localhost" to a different IP address? You need to look into port forwarding.

Comment: although mysql proxies were built to handle more complicated stuffs such as load balancing or failover recovery, I think it also suits your requirement here so you can host it on localhost, and connect to your RDS